# How to save / download attachments from outlook emails with C#

Tags: c#

i get a task to download / save attachments from specific email

I already write code from references from many website (including stack overflow answer) , but the Console application wont save the attachments .

Here's my code

```
 try
            {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application MyApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace MailNS = MyApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder MyInbox = null;

                MyInbox = MailNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem InboxMailItem = null;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems = MyInbox.Items;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailitem = MyApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                string Query = "[Subject] = 'Test'";

                InboxMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oItems.Find(Query);

                while(InboxMailItem != null)
                {
                    Outlook.Attachments attachments =  InboxMailItem.Attachments;
                    if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Outlook.Attachment attachment = attachments[i];

                            string filename = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\u532246\Desktop", attachment.FileName);
                            attachment.SaveAsFile(filename);

                            Console.WriteLine("berhasil");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                 break;
                }

                MyApp = null;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Perhaps i did something wrong here , because im new to this kind of task ..

Thankyou for the help , i really appreciate

Comment: Any errors? What did debugging reveal?

Comment: @John  Didnt reveal anything, its just suddenly close like it doesnt find the email i want , but when i try to read the body email in the while statements, it does read the body email, but after that it close and the attachment wont appear in the directory path

Comment: @John that `catch(Exception) { }` "solves" all the problems ;)

Comment: So if you step through, does it get to the "Berhasil" line? Did you run this without the try/catch block around it (which you've presumably added to hide errors).

Comment: It doesnt get to the berhasil line, and already try to run without the try / catch

Comment: @Caius Jard sry haha i forgot to remove the try catch, but still not working

Comment: Oh well nvm, i put the wrong index in the for condition so it always out of bounds ..

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the attachments array index starts at 1 and not at 0, as you have used in the example code you have posted.

So your code for the `for` loop should be:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
{
    Outlook.Attachment attachment = attachments[i];

    string filename = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\u532246\Desktop", attachment.FileName);
    attachment.SaveAsFile(filename);

    Console.WriteLine("berhasil");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```